# Flask deployment using twistd

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, twistd

[In the flask doco](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#twisted-web) the following description is shown of deploying a flask app under twistd.

```
twistd web --wsgi myproject.app
```

I have a foo.py which looks like this

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

So I expected to be able to run that under twistd like this

```
twistd web --wsgi foo.app
```

but twistd doesn't like that (just spits out the help text).

What am I doing wrong ?

BTW in case it matters I'm running this in a virtualenv (in which I have installed both flask and twisted) and the current directory when I issue the twistd command contains foo.py .

---

**EDIT**: The version of twistd I am using is 18.7.0

I had failed to notice (until prompted to by Peter Gibson's comment ) that after the help text appears the message "No such WSGI application: 'foo.app'" appears.

Comment: What version of twistd/twisted are you using?

Comment: Do you get an error after the help text such as "No such WSGI Application"?

Comment: Thanks for your response Peter. I've updated the question to respond to your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the current directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. Try

```
PYTHONPATH=. twistd web --wsgi foo.app
```

Or on Windows (untested)

```
set PYTHONPATH=.
twistd web --wsgi foo.app
```

Comment: Thanks. I've never seen a bash command quite like that before - I should just use it exactly as shown here ?

Comment: That syntax modifies PYTHONPATH for the current command only. Alternatively you could `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.` which will persist for that session, and also appends the current directory `.` to PYTHONPATH instead of overwriting it (in case you have other PYTHONPATH customisations in your .bashrc say)

Comment: That's excellent thanks. I never knew you could do that thing with modifying PYTHONPATH for that command only. Thanks for your help it is working now.

Comment: Your answer is not os-agnostic.  So it does not work in windows.  It would help to see a way to resolve the OP from within a python program in a way that is agnostic with respect to os.

Comment: @CodeMed thanks I've updated with an example for Windows, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you and +1.  We actually solved it in an os-agnostic way yesterday by using python.  We set the environment variable with `os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '.'`  . And then we ran the `twistd web --wsgi foo.app` using python's subprocess module.  The python approach does not require you to write separate code for every operating system.